# Как предотвратить повторные запросы от одного пользователя

Tags: база-данных

На сайте пользователям раз в сутки доступен 1 подарок. Интерфейс сайта не позволяет получить более одного подарка в сутки. Так же перед зачислением подарка пользователю идет проверка на возможность его получения путем проверки записей в БД о полученных ранее гифтов в течении суток. Если же отправить сразу два запроса, например через консоль браузера, то сервер на оба запроса отвечает положительно. Видимо после первого запроса запись не успевает добавиться в БД и сервер считает, что ранее пользователь не получал подарки в текущих сутках. Вопрос в том, как запретить повторное получение подарка в течении одних суток.
БД mariaDB. Запросы обрабатываются через nginx, php.

Comment: Сутки - от полуночи до полуночи? Создайте для таблицы уникальный индекс по id пользователя и дате (без времени).

Answer (score 2):

Делаем таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE gifts ( giftdatetime DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                     giftdate DATE AS (DATE(giftdatetime)),
                     userid BIGINT,
                     UNIQUE (giftdate, userid) );
```

и просто вставляем в неё идентификатор пользователя:

```
INSERT INTO gifts (userid) VALUES ({идентификатор пользователя});
```

Если пользователь сегодня уже участвовал в процессе - возникнет ошибка дублирования уникального ключа, которая легко ловится на клиенте. И никакие "Если же отправить сразу два запроса" это не объедут.

Answer (score 2):

Предложенный @Akina вариант валидный, но предложу другой вариант. Генерируйте key для каждого пользователя так, чтоб при множественной попытке вставки результат был всегда одним.

```
@giftKey = day(serverTime вы можете ключ на сервере) + "_{giftType}" + "_" +"{userId}"

CREATE TABLE gifts ( giftdatetime DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                     giftKey TEXT, (тут не принципиально)
                     userid BIGINT,
                     UNIQUE (giftKey) ); 

INSERT INTO gifts (@giftKey, @userid) VALUES ({идентификатор пользователя});
```

В чем принципиальная разница? В случае если вам действительно нужно будет дать приз в этот же день по другой любой причине вы спокойно это сделаете указав причину либо вовсе добавив GUID к ключу если это приз вручаемый несколько раз .... А сделать по той же причине с тем же ключом не удаться.

Comment: *В случае если вам действительно нужно будет дать приз в этот же день по другой любой причине* В моём решении для этого достаточно добавить поле `giftreasonID` и включить его в уникальный индекс. Получится то же, что и у Вас - только не надо на клиенте огород городить с генерацией @giftKey.

Comment: @Akina Да всё верно кто спорит? + 1 от меня за ваш ответ

Comment: Идея моего ответа. генерировать частично уникальность вне базы. Которое решается легко с небольшими изменениями вашего ответа.

Comment: *генерировать частично уникальность вне базы* А смысл? ведь непременно найдётся умник, который попробует это изменить и поиметь два подарка - борись потом с такими...

Comment: *ведь непременно найдётся умник, который попробует это изменить и поиметь два подарка - борись потом с такими...* - Тут ведь не задача борьбы с умниками. Взламывают и не такое. Только вот смысл. Если нет идеи то и нет смысла. А умник старающийся сломать  какой либо сайт просто для прикола это дурак. А с дураками что бороться? Это вообще не про программирование.

Comment: *попробует это изменить и поиметь два подарка* - это делается так чтоб подарки он сам не мог получить иначе это воровство. Против воровства контролируется места потенциальных атак и уязвивостей, ну это совсем другая задача. И будет звучать примерно "как сделать так чтоб юзер не смог сам назначить себе приз?"